# "war-concomitant event" as a adjectival phrase

Tags: style, compounds, adjective-phrases

Can I use "war-concomitant" with a hyphen as adjectival phrase? 
I am aware that I can say "an event concomitant with war", but I need to use it as"war-concomitant" as in "war-concomitant event" for example

> Thus war-concomitant *The Four Quartets*, I argue, should not be seen
>   as  war poetry in relation to the Second World War in the same sense
>   that post-war The Waste Land is in relation to Great War.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very dubious about saying that *The Four Quartets* was *concomitant* with the war. *Concomitant* implies that there is an inherent, necessary connection between the work and the war; but you appear to be claiming just the opposite, that the fact that the work was composed during the war is merely a historical accident.

I think the word you are looking for is *wartime*. And some minor points:

- *Thus* implies argument, so postponing and parenthesizing *I argue* is very odd: you should either lead with *I argue* (and associate *thus* with it, if you feel the *thus* is necessary) or drop it altogether.
- It is usual to drop a leading *The* in the title to accommodate a necessary determiner before the modifiers.
- The *is* in the final clause is so remote from its antecedent *be seen* that the connection is lost; I'd echo, or build a less awkward expression than *seen as war poetry in relation to* to parallel.

> I thus argue that *The Four Quartets* should not be seen as war poetry in the same sense as *The Waste Land*: the wartime *Four Quartets* does not stand in the same relation to the Second World War as the postwar *Waste Land* does to the Great War.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, yes. I've never seen that particular adjectival phrase before but it's grammatically correct and is easily understood.

For the sake of posterity, here are some references:

- http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_adjectives.htm
- http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/040201hyphadj.htm

Answer (score 1):

"Concomitant" is such an unusual word that I can't really say there are any "normal" ways to use it. Anyone who knows the word will understand what you mean.

That said, it does seem odd to me. I'm guessing you want a hyphenated, adjectival phrase, in order to parallel "post-war"? I can't think of any other phrase that captures the meaning, and I think the majority of writers would simply change the structure. Enforcing that parallel structure makes your sentence seem, well poetic—which may be exactly what you want. And being poetic also lets you get away with all sorts of unusual-but-understandable word choices!